# "Exception in thread 'main'" error with Apache Ant on CentOS 6.4

Tags: java, apache, ant, centos

I'm attempting to run Apache Ant for the purpose of compiling OpenGTS. While attempting to run any "ant" command I'm getting the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher. Program will exit.
```

Previously I was getting a message stating "JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly" and after reading several forum threads, was able to solve that by updating the path:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

Another thread stated a "CLASS PATH" issue but if I'm able to run "ant" anywhere in the terminal, wouldn't the path be correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to set `ANT_HOME` to the directory where you installed ant. Refer to [Installling Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html).

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm going to run through the binary install process. It appears that using "yum install ant" may have been a mistake. I will post my results when I'm finished reinstalling.

Comment: Comments on another SO post suggest others had issues with the CentOS any package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698809/apache-ant-1-8-on-centos

Answer (score 1):

You need to export `ANT_HOME` too, just make sure it is installed first on your system

```
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/ant";
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a wrong permission on `/opt/ant/lib` folder.