# Apache Ant java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, ant

Possible Answer [Stack Over flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214979/ant-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-tools)

My problem is same as described in the above thread.I went throught the solution and its not working.
**ant compile** working perfectly. **ant jar** saying cant load the main class

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LoadServer (wrong name: org/module/loader/LoadServer)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I did the following in commnad line

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_21"
ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant/"
PATH="$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Morever if I start a new terminal and type **echo$JAVA_HOME** its showing the above result but **echo$ANT_HOME** is giving null.

[here is a screen shot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz8w_lUmpqFaUllWWlZvQ3d6YUU/edit?usp=sharing)

Initial Error

```
     <project name="Raxa-4" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir"      value="src"/>
    <property name="prop.dir"     value="properties"/>
    <property name="resource.dir" value="resource"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"      value="lib"/>
    <property name="build.dir"    value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir"  value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"      value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"   value="org.raxa.module.loader.LoadServer"/>

    <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
            <fileset dir="${prop.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

   <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
         <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        </jar>
    </target>


    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>

    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

Edited:

```
    <property name="src.dir"      value="src"/>
    <property name="prop.dir"     value="properties"/>
    <property name="resource.dir" value="resource"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"      value="lib"/>
    <property name="build.dir"    value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir"  value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"      value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class"   value="org.raxa.module.loader.LoadServer"/>

    <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" />
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
            <fileset dir="${prop.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

   <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>


    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

**NEW ERROR** on ant run

run:

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
 [java]     at org.raxa.module.scheduler.TimeSetter.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.raxa.module.loader.LoadServer.main(Unknown Source)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 [java]     ... 2 more
 [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD FAILED
/home/atul/Documents/workspace2/Raxa-4/build.xml:41: Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken pla
```

Comment: Let's see your `build.xml`.

Comment: look at the edit.Edited build.xml

Comment: Your `jar` target classpath should also include the `classes.dir` folder.

Comment: based on this: _but echo$ANT_HOME is giving null_ i think your ANT was not properly configured. If you go to '/usr/share/ant/bin' and execute './ant' do you get anything? If yes You could try by removing the last slash at the end of _ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant/"_

Comment: yeah thanks..I have edited it and its working.But its unable to load external libraries.Is something wrong on the new edit?

Comment: external library i s located in lib directory like mysql.jar,asterisk-java.jar

Comment: the problem is when you invoke the task 'compile'?

Comment: the initial problem was solved.ant compile and ant jar is working fine.Now getting problem in ant run

Comment: this this one: <java classname="${main-class}" fork="true" >         
  <classpath>
    <path refid="classpath"/>
    <pathelement location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</java>

Comment: Whats difference between your suggestion and mycode?

Comment: you execute the main class directly and uses your jar as any other library. Did you at least try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that your classpath gets overriden. Try this one:

```
<java classname="${main-class}" fork="true" >
  <classpath>
    <path refid="classpath"/>
    <pathelement location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</classpath> </java>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ANT_HOME` defined because the shell script `ant` will set that for you. However, if you did `EXPORT ANT_HOME`, you'll see it when you start a new terminal. Until you export an environment variable, it won't show up in child processes.

I noticed that the Ant class isn't showing up in the call. You should have seen some call to `org.apache.tools.ant` somewhere in the stack trace if this was an Ant issue. Can you run any other build task? Try:

```
$ ant clean
```

Does that work?

Ant has extensive debugging trace which shows you way more information than you want to know. Try running `ant` with the `-d` parameter:

```
$ ant -d compile | tee ant.out
```

This will produce a lot of output which is why you need to pipe this into a file. Look at `ant.out` and see where it's failing. Did it call the `compile` task?

The ant-launcher calls `ant.jar` which then calls `org.ant.tools.taskdefs.javac` (If I remember the path) which then does a system command to call the `javac` executable directly. One of the things the dump will show is the exact command being executed when the compilation is done.

This will probably help you find where the error is happening. It could be that `javac` itself isn't executing, or that it is missing. I've seen this before where someone accidentally pointed `JAVA_HOME` to a JRE and not a JDK. I've also seen this where the executable was 64bits, but the OS was 32bits.

If the dump shows you the actual Java command being executed, see if you can copy it, and paste it into a shell script and execute the `javac` command directly. This way, we can see if the issue is with `javac` or with Ant. If you can execute `javac` without Ant, it's an Ant issue. Otherwise, it's an issue with your Java installation.